# Crash page on Meta directs users to Meta

Tags: feature-request, 500-server-error

The generic "oops" crash page on Meta directs users to report the issue at meta (optionally). There's a stack overflow joke in here somewhere...

Perhaps meta should replace that text with another site or email (or just remove it).

[alt text http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/7690/sometaerror.png](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/7690/sometaerror.png)

Comment: Where is the kitty cat?

Comment: It was burriewd under the stack when it overflowed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image of the error isn't joke enough for you? get it? The dialog image box?

Comment: Cannot understand any error messages without lolcats.

Comment: Very well; your cleverness exceeds expectations yet again

Answer (score 4):

Excellent find!

We should make sure to redirect people to the meta.meta.stackoverflow.com and not just the normal meta.

;)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're crashing when asking a question, then you can report the error on meta.

The joke is pretty good though. :)